# Add contact programmatically, with number phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, contacts, silverlight-5.0

I want programmatically add a contact. I follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207024(v=vs.105).aspx). With this I can add all information about contact WITHOUT his number phone. Class `StoredContact` doesn't have 'phone number' property. I'm stuck on this. I know about `SaveContactTask`, but I want to save contact fully programmatically, without any user inputs. I know is possible, because exist app who doing it: FB, VK for example. Please, help me, how can I save full contact info with phone number programmatically, or tell me why I can't do it, and how some apps do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried following code?

```
  IDictionary<string, object> props = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync();
   props.Add(KnownContactProperties.Telephone, "yourtelephone");
        props.Add(KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, "mobileTele");
        props.Add(KnownContactProperties.AlternateMobileTelephone, "mobileTele");
        props.Add(KnownContactProperties.WorkTelephone, "mobileTele");
        props.Add(KnownContactProperties.AlternateWorkTelephone, "mobileTele");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.aspx) namespace

Note: the Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts namespace is only supported by WP8.1

Comment: ContactPickerUI doesn't support phone platform.  Minimum supported phone None supported

Comment: ApplicationModel.Contacts used the same Contact class without phone number property

Comment: @daleijn use `Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPhone` to add a phone number

Comment: ok, but how can I use it to add contact to the phone? I don't see necessary methods for this